# Defined user role to access plugin's pages

Tags: plugins, admin, users, user-roles

I Have two plugin installed `Job Manager` and `Events` and i want to defined User roles to access These plugin's created pages (Plugin Pages).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/screenshots/) for access control on pages but you need to set which pages give these control. You can also control the comment, read and more.

Please check this may help you.